# Double factorials: proper way to interpret/evaluate?

Tags: factorial

Sorry for asking, but after watching videos, I’m not sure what is proper way to count double factorials. Is it first or second way?

1st way: $3!! = 1 \cdot 3 = 3$
2nd way: $3!! = (3!)! = 6! = 720$

Comment: The real use case of $(n!)!$ is so rare that it is almost always $n!!=n(n-2)\dots (n-2\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor)$ as a single operation not taking factorial twice.  Anyway, $1\times 3=3\neq 1$.

Comment: While we wait for the answerer and the commenter to duke it out haha, I'm going to edit your title to better reflect your intention (I believe). When I first saw the title, I thought it was going to be asking how to solve equations like $n!! = m$ for given $m$. ¶ For what it's worth, I think $n!! = n(n-2)(n-4) \cdots$ is more common, but I would always explain it in the text. A text that doesn't explain it (or give an example) is slightly derelict in duty, I feel.

Comment: To @Eminem1109: Check this resource: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're encountering this in a factorial setting, then it's the second way:

$$n!! \text{ means } (n!)!$$

So, in your example, yes, you would have:

$$3!! = (3!)! = (6)! = 6! = 720$$

**But**! Beware that you are not actually encountering the [**double factorial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) symbol at the aforelinked wikipage.